# Why use synchronous_standby_names = 'barman_receive_wal' will cause database aberrant?

Tags: postgresql, barman, repmgr

Use `barman`'s [synchronous_standby_names](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.11/#archiving-features) feature in PostgreSQL's `postgresql.conf` file

```
synchronous_standby_names = 'barman_receive_wal'
```

Can't do these operations:

- createuser(hanging)
- createdb(hanging)
- can't save data in primary database if use `repmgr` for replication

Main configuration for them is

```
max_wal_senders = 10
max_replication_slots = 10
shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@backup_server:/var/lib/barman/mydb/incoming/%f'
synchronous_standby_names = 'barman_receive_wal'
```

If remove `synchronous_standby_names` from this configuration, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've set up PostgreSQL to push WAL files to `barman` via `archive_command` - is `barman` also set up for [WAL streaming](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.11/#standard-archiving-wal-streaming-...-or-both)? If that's not the case, there will be no synchronous standby with the name `barman_receive_wal` and hence any writes to the primary will not succeed, as PostgreSQL is waiting for a standby commit confirmation which never arrives.